# Maximum cliques of the transitive closure of a chordal DAG

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, directed-graphs

Let $G=(V,A)$ be a directed acyclic graph, for which the underlying
undirected graph is chordal (so that every induced cycle in the
underlying undirected graph is a triangle).

It is known that in a chordal graph the number of *maximum cliques*
is linearly bounded in the number $|V|$ of vertices.

Let $G'=(V,A')$ be the transitive closure of $G$, so that for
every directed path $p= (v_i,\ldots,v_j)$ from $v_i$ to $v_j$
in $G$, there exists a directed edge $(v_i,v_j)$ in $A'$.

> **Question:** Is there any polynomial/linear bound on the number
> of maximum cliques in the undirected graph that underlies $G'$?

Comment: I'll leave this as a comment because I'm hoping to do better, but here's a quadratic lower bound. Let $G$ be a tree on $2k+1$ vertices $\{u_1, \dots, u_k, v, w_1, \dots, w_k\}$ with all edges of the form $u_i \to v$ and $v \to w_j$. This has no cycles at all, so the condition is satisfied; but $G'$ adds all edges $u_i \to w_j$, so it has $(\frac k2)^2$ maximum cliques of the form $\{u_i, v, w_j\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following graph, with edges oriented from left to right :
[image: Graph]

This graph is chordal.

The transitive closure of this graph is the complete graph without every vertical edges.

A clique in the transitive closure is any subset of the vertices such that there isn't two vertices with the same $x$ coordinate.

A maximal clique is thus a maximal set of such vertices, so one for each different $x$ coordinate.

There is an exponential number of those : $2^{\frac {n-1} 3}$.

This construction isn't optimal, but I guess this lower bound gives the idea.

Comment: Intuitive counterexample, thank you!